# Why do I keep getting a line 93 error saying TwitterClient not defined when it is defined in a class above?

Tags: python

This is for tweepy. It says

> TwitterClient not defined.

```
import re 
import tweepy 
from tweepy import OAuthHandler 
from textblob import TextBlob 
class TwitterClient(object):
    '''
   Generic Twitter Class for sentiment analysis. 
    '''
    def __init__(self): 
        ''' 
    Class constructor or initialization method. 
        '''
        # keys and tokens from the Twitter Dev Console 
        consumer_key = 'remove'
        consumer_secret = 'remove'
        access_token = 'remove-remove'
        access_token_secret = 'remove'

        # attempt authentication 
        try: 
        # create OAuthHandler object 
            self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 
        # set access token and secret 
            self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret) 
        # create tweepy API object to fetch tweets 
            self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth) 
        except: 
            print("Error: Authentication Failed") 

    def clean_tweet(self, tweet): 
        ''' 
        Utility function to clean tweet text by removing links, special characters 
        using simple regex statements. 
        '''
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())
    def get_tweet_sentiment(self, tweet): 
        ''' 
        Utility function to classify sentiment of passed tweet 
        using textblob's sentiment method 
        '''
        # create TextBlob object of passed tweet text 
        analysis = TextBlob(self.clean_tweet(tweet)) 
        # set sentiment 
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0: 
            return 'positive'
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0: 
            return 'neutral'
        else: 
            return 'negative'
    def get_tweets(self, query, count = 10): 
        ''' 
        Main function to fetch tweets and parse them. 
        '''
        # empty list to store parsed tweets 
        tweets = [] 
        try: 
            # call twitter api to fetch tweets 
                fetched_tweets = self.api.search(q = query, count = count) 

            # parsing tweets one by one 
                for tweet in fetched_tweets: 
                # empty dictionary to store required params of a tweet 
                    parsed_tweet = {} 

                # saving text of tweet 
                    parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text 
                # saving sentiment of tweet 
                    parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.text)
                # appending parsed tweet to tweets list 
                    if tweet.retweet_count > 0: 
                    # if tweet has retweets, ensure that it is appended only once 
                        if parsed_tweet not in tweets: 
                            tweets.append(parsed_tweet) 
                        else: 
                            tweets.append(parsed_tweet) 

                # return parsed tweets 
                return tweets 

        except tweepy.TweepError as e: 
            #print error (if any) 
                print("Error : " + str(e)) 

    def main():
            #creating object of TwitterClient Class 
        api = TwitterClient()
            #calling function to get tweets 
        tweets = api.get_tweets(query = 'ADF', count = 200) 

        #picking positive tweets from tweets 
        ptweets = [tweet for  tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive'] 
    #       percentage of positive tweets 
        print("Positive tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ptweets)/len(tweets))) 
            #picking negative tweets from tweets 
        ntweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'negative'] 
            #percentage of negative tweets 
        print("Negative tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ntweets)/len(tweets))) 
            #percentage of neutral tweets \
        netweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'neutral']
        print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*(len(netweets)/len(tweets))))
            #printing first 5 positive tweets 
        print("\n\nPositive tweets:")
        for tweet in ptweets[:10]:
            print(tweet['text'])
            #printing first 5 negative tweets  
        print("\n\nNegative tweets:") 
        for tweet in ntweets[:10]: 
            print(tweet['text']) 
    if __name__ == "__main__": 
                #calling main function 
            main()
```

Comment: In `class TwitterClient(object):`, is object a parameter? If so, it needs to be included in the `__init__` definition instead.

Comment: Am I also correct to say that `main()` is not part of `TwitterClient()`?

Comment: Make sure the indentation in the question matches your actual indentation. We tried to clean up the question formatting, but it looks like things were too messed up for us to get it right. Post your actual code, then use Ctl-k to indent it 4 places.

Comment: Thanks. That code looks like the indents I have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cut-down version of your code which demonstrates the problem.

```
class TwitterClient(object):
    None

    def main():
        api = TwitterClient()
        print("main()")


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Note the indentation of both `main()` and `if __name__ == "__main__"` place them under the definition of TwitterClient itself. Hence the error, in Python 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter-55610165.py", line 2, in <module>
    class TwitterClient(object):
  File "twitter-55610165.py", line 11, in TwitterClient
    main()
  File "twitter-55610165.py", line 6, in main
    api = TwitterClient()
NameError: name 'TwitterClient' is not defined
```

`TwitterClient` is not defined because the class definition of `TwitterClient` has not finished - you're still inside it. The if is at the class scope level, so runs at time of definition of the class. Indentation determines a lot about scope in Python.

With small but important changes in whitespace, to take `main()` and `if __name__ ...` out of the TwitterClient scope and put them back at the main scope, the problem goes away.

```
class TwitterClient(object):
    None

def main():
    api = TwitterClient()
    print("main()")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

ie these constructs are now at the same indent level as `TwitterClient`, further left by one level of indentation.

```
$ python3 twitter-55610165.py
main()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You explained that perfectly too clearly. I can't believe I overlooked that. I was so focused on the actual code possibly being wrong. Guess I can't do python yet, lol

Comment: Now I just have to work on improving it/training it better. I just tested it and it looks mostly accurate, but I tried an analysis of Hillary and it gave this as a positive tweet: RT @Lrihendry: Seems clear to me, Mueller quit digging when all of his tunnels led to Hillary, Obama and Democrats.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to remove `main()` from the `TwitterClient()` definition.
The exact problem is that `main()` is *inside* the `TwitterClient()`, so in other words you haven't finished defining `TwitterClient()`, so python is throwing errors.

How to fix

The easiest solution is to move `main()` and `if __name__...` lines from the `TwitterClient()` definition. That will get rid of your current error. This code should work:

import re 
    import tweepy 
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler 
    from textblob import TextBlob 
    class TwitterClient(object):
        '''
       Generic Twitter Class for sentiment analysis. 
        '''
        def **init**(self): 
            ''' 
        Class constructor or initialization method. 
            '''
            # keys and tokens from the Twitter Dev Console 
            consumer_key = 'remove'
            consumer_secret = 'remove'
            access_token = 'remove-remove'
            access_token_secret = 'remove'

```
        # attempt authentication 
        try: 
        # create OAuthHandler object 
            self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 
        # set access token and secret 
            self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret) 
        # create tweepy API object to fetch tweets 
            self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth) 
        except: 
            print("Error: Authentication Failed") 

    def clean_tweet(self, tweet): 
        ''' 
        Utility function to clean tweet text by removing links, special characters 
        using simple regex statements. 
        '''
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())
    def get_tweet_sentiment(self, tweet): 
        ''' 
        Utility function to classify sentiment of passed tweet 
        using textblob's sentiment method 
        '''
        # create TextBlob object of passed tweet text 
        analysis = TextBlob(self.clean_tweet(tweet)) 
        # set sentiment 
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0: 
            return 'positive'
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0: 
            return 'neutral'
        else: 
            return 'negative'
    def get_tweets(self, query, count = 10): 
        ''' 
        Main function to fetch tweets and parse them. 
        '''
        # empty list to store parsed tweets 
        tweets = [] 
        try: 
            # call twitter api to fetch tweets 
                fetched_tweets = self.api.search(q = query, count = count) 

            # parsing tweets one by one 
                for tweet in fetched_tweets: 
                # empty dictionary to store required params of a tweet 
                    parsed_tweet = {} 

                # saving text of tweet 
                    parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text 
                # saving sentiment of tweet 
                    parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.text)
                # appending parsed tweet to tweets list 
                    if tweet.retweet_count > 0: 
                    # if tweet has retweets, ensure that it is appended only once 
                        if parsed_tweet not in tweets: 
                            tweets.append(parsed_tweet) 
                        else: 
                            tweets.append(parsed_tweet) 

                # return parsed tweets 
                return tweets 

        except tweepy.TweepError as e: 
            #print error (if any) 
                print("Error : " + str(e)) 

def main():
        #creating object of TwitterClient Class 
    api = TwitterClient()
        #calling function to get tweets 
    tweets = api.get_tweets(query = 'ADF', count = 200) 

        #picking positive tweets from tweets 
    ptweets = [tweet for  tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive'] 
        #percentage of positive tweets 
    print("Positive tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ptweets)/len(tweets))) 
        #picking negative tweets from tweets 
    ntweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'negative'] 
        #percentage of negative tweets 
    print("Negative tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ntweets)/len(tweets))) 
        #percentage of neutral tweets \
    netweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'neutral']
    print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*(len(netweets)/len(tweets))))
        #printing first 5 positive tweets 
    print("\n\nPositive tweets:")
    for tweet in ptweets[:10]:
        print(tweet['text'])
        #printing first 5 negative tweets  
    print("\n\nNegative tweets:") 
    for tweet in ntweets[:10]: 
            print(tweet['text']) 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    #calling main function 
    main()
```